How to annotate rosbag data for Machine Learning applications?
I have collected sensor data in a rosbag in the form of:

Point clouds (/points2)
IMU Sensors
GPS (/fix data)
GPS Velocity (/fix_velocity)
Compressed Images

etc.
I want to annotate and share this data for machine learning applications. The annotation will basically comprise of events such as major IMU events in correspondance with other sensor data, specific pose descriptions etc.
I request inputs on what tools/softwares can I use to annotate the rosbag files keeping in mind that the rosbags are to be used in machine learning applications.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
